# Ghost gives me 404 error on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, ghost-blog, ghost

As you can see I get no errors during `ghost start`

[image]

but when I actually go to the page http://13.125.83.25 (Elastic IP of the EC2 instance), there's nothing. page doesn't load anything. no idea why this happens, I'm new to ghost module. what am I missing?

here's `config.production.json` below.

```
{
  "url": "http://13.125.83.25",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "",
      "password": "", // just hided
      "database": ""
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/var/www/ghost/content"
  }
}
```

and Here's `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fill your **IP/DomainName** near the **server_name** and make sure you are having the right **port** near the **proxy_pass** beacause sometimes when you run **`ghost restart`** it changes the port number.So in order to check the port number run the folowing command **`ghost ls`** and check the port number of your running ghost process.Use the following config for your Nginx server,hope it helps.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name 13.125.83.25;
    root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root;

    location /blog {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```